# How can I create instance variable based on OS version

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

How can I define instance variable based on the iOS verison, for example
`CNContactStore` is available since `iOS9.0` and `ABAddressBook` is deprecated in `9.0` but I want to create two variable depends upon iOS version. My Approach is

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    var addressBookRef: ABAddressBook? = nil
} else {
    var contactStore : CNContactStore? = nil
}
```

If I do this inside a method body, works fine but I want it to be define globally and can be access throughout the class but giving me error if I do it like this

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
var contactStore : CNContactStore? = nil
```

Need some suggestions. How do I achieve this. I've no idea if I release `@available(iOS 9.0, *)`, it will crash my app on iOS 8.x or below?

Comment: You will have to declare both variables as optional and supply a value to only one based on #available and then at appropriate places unwrap the variables and act accordingly

Comment: variable of type `CNContactStore` will crash my app on lower version? I do not have device to test on lower version?

Comment: No, it won't since you will be compiling against the higher level SDK.  The #available will ensure that that code doesn't run on lower iOS versions.

Comment: But I've to declare the variable globally of type `CNContactStore` or not?

Comment: Yes, you need to declare both variables. The #available is a run time check, without both variables being declared your code won't compile

Comment: A better approach could be to wrap your CNContactStore/ABAddresBook functionality inside classes that inherit from a common superclass with functions that implement your required methods and map the to the appropriate framework. Then you can instantiate the appropriate subclass based on version and not have to check the version everywhere.

Comment: Can you please write two lines or example to demonstrate, How? Little bit confuse in version checking control :(. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In that case I would use a wrapper class mimic even ABAddressBook and CNContactStore behaviour so all the call to their methods should be done through this class.

A quick approach for what you are looking could be like this:

```
class ContactWrapper {
    var contactBook: NSObject?


    init() {
        if #available(iOS 9, *) {
            contactBook = CNContactStore.init()
        } else {
            contactBook = ABAddressBookCreate().takeRetainedValue() as? NSObject
        }

    }
}
```